# Doctrine 1 selecting from one table with 2 alias

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table a, table b
WHERE a.col1=b.col1
AND a.col2= b.col2 
AND a.col3= b.col3 
AND a.col4 = b.col4 
AND a.id <> b.id
```

that searches duplicates in table.
I need to query this by Doctrine 1, but getting error. Here is my code:

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('table a, table b')
    ->where('a.col1= b.col1')
    ->andWhere('a.col2= b.col2')
    ->andWhere('a.col3= b.col3')
    ->andWhere('a.col4= b.col4')
    ->andWhere('a.id <> b.id');
```

and error is:

```
"Table" with an alias of "b" in your query does not reference the parent component it is related to.
```

What is the right way to do, what i need?

Comment: Please have look at [`Documentation`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) once again.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i'm using Doctrine 1, and i read documentation, but didn't find answer for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there were no relation in table, I added it in schema.yml to my entity:

```
  relations:
    SomeTable:
      class: SomeTable
```

so it works.